# Dry coding JS and mongoDB queries, remove repetitive functions

Tags: javascript, mongodb

so i have a codeblock:

```
Vampire.find({ gender: `f` }, (err, foundVamps) => {
    if (err) console.log(err);

    console.log(foundVamps);
    process.exit();
}) 
// worked

// Select all vamps with over 500 victims
 Vampire.find({ victims: { $gt: 500 } }, (err, foundVamps) => {
    if (err) console.log(err);

    console.log(foundVamps);
    process.exit();
}) 
// worked

// Select all vamps with less than or equal to 150 victims
 Vampire.find({ victims: { $lte: 150 } }, (err, foundVamps) => {
    if (err) console.log(err);

    console.log(foundVamps);
    process.exit();
})
```

as you can see, for each query, its the same if error console log, and if not consolelog the same variable, is there a way i can dry code this in order to save time having to always type it out? maybe something like

```
const quickFn = (...) => (...);
```

or something
im relatively new to JS by comparison but there has to be something out there to make this more DRY code? any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Vampire is an array??

Comment: @sonEtLumiere It's a Mongoose model

Comment: can you store those data into an array? you can use filter method, check my answer

Answer (score 0):

not sure who posted this answer because they deleted it right after posting, but it was:

```
const quickFn = filter =>  Vampire.find(filter, (err, foundVamps) => {
    if (err) console.log(err);

    console.log(foundVamps);
    // process.exit(); // do you really need this?
});


// Usage
quickFn({ gender: `f` });
// Select all vamps with over 500 victims
quickFn({ victims: { $gt: 500 } });
// Select all vamps with less than or equal to 150 victims
quickFn({ victims: { $lte: 150 } });
```

i wanted to thank that person because it was perfect for my needs

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps

```js
let vampire = [{gender: 'f', gt: 500}, 
               {gender: 'm', gt: 120},
               {gender: 'f', gt: 100},
               {gender: 'f', gt: 505}
];


let vampiresF = vampire.filter(x => x.gender == 'f');
console.log(vampiresF);
    
let vampiresM = vampire.filter(x => x.gender == 'm');
console.log(vampiresM);

let from120to150 = vampire.filter(x => x.gt >= 120 && x.gt <=500);
console.log(from120to150);
```